# Do I have to turn on ngx_http_access_module?

Tags: nginx, ngx-http-access-module

Do I have to turn on ngx_http_access_module?

I don't see any installation steps in the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) - except the config file of course. Unlike the [docs of gzip_static_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html) where they state:

> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the `--with-http_gzip_static_module` configuration parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `nginx -V` on your machine and your will see if your nginx was compiled with that module or not

> nginx -V
>
> nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
>   built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
>   TLS SNI support enabled
>
> configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads

Above is default nginx on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As you can see default one is compiled with that

**Edit-1: Default modules**

So there are two things when we talk about default modules.

One is when you download the source code and run `./configure` just before compiling. This will follow nginx documentation which means if documentation says `This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_gzip_static_module configuration parameter.`. Then the module will not be built

Second one is when you install nginx using your OS package manager using let's say `sudo apt-get install -y nginx`. This will come with modules that may not be specified as default in the Nginx documentation but are default in the OS Nginx package distribution.

Comment: It's not listed in my config... But I sometimes see the flag `--without-http_access_module` which makes me thing that **ngx_http_access_module** is installed by default, isn't it? I didn't block any IP address yet so I can't confirm...

Comment: `without` means the access module is missing

Comment: I'd say `--without-http_access_module` makes your nginx omit the module **ngx_http_access_module**.

Comment: I see, I wrote it in a bad by **sometimes** I meant **in some posts** not in my config. Sorry, my bad. >]

Comment: I would like to accept the answer but I don't know if by sentence **As you can see default one is compiled with that** you mean **Yeah, ngx_http_access_module is included by default**?

Comment: @zatziky, I added a para to explain. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first part of the first answer is incorrect:

> Run nginx -V on your machine and your will see if your nginx was compiled with that module or not

Per nginx, they compile in all modules that do not require external dependencies *by default* and these do not show in nginx -V; you would have to implicitly compile *without* it.

I had a similar problem - couldn't get blocking to work and thought the module wasn't compiled in or available - it actually was and nginx -V did *not* list it. Correct configuration is:

```
location ~* /maint {
    allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    deny all;
}
```

It's the tilde star at the beginning of the clause that I was missing. Works perfectly now and I didn't touch any modules or compile anything.

[Serverfault similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/832975/nginx-block-access-to-url)

[nginx block documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration)

[nginx module compiling](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#selecting-the-nginx-modules-to-build)